# Application has started to crash after updating for iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, app-store-connect

I have archived and uploaded the build file of my swift application to iTunes Connect and started to use TestFlight Beta Testing with internal testers from my developing team. After a while, I have made some updates and bug-fixes (as expected :)), archived new version, uploaded the new build file to iTunes Connect and disabled the old application. However, when the testers had installed the new app, **they have started to face crashes while application is launching** and there is not any crash report generated. I am using the same version without any crash/problem installing the app directly from XCode via cable, but people who are installing via iTunes Connect keeps crashing. I am checking my iTunes Connect again and again. I have **updated version info** in Versions segment, **enabled TestFlight Beta Testing** for new version (it automatically disabled the older one).

Testers have tried deleting the old version from their devices, but still crashing. What might be the problem?

Comment: There's not enough information here to answer your question but it's pretty safe to say it's not related to testflight beta testing. Please add some information from the crash reports.

Comment: I have editted my question to improve the details provided as much as I can. However, I have to say there is not any crash or problem when the application is loaded directly from XCode via cable. Only people who installs the app using iTunes Connect faces this problem. And furthermore, **no crash report** is generated.

Comment: I'm willing to bet there is a crash reported to the console on the tester's device when your app fails.  I would suggest asking your users to send you a copy of their console after the crash occurs. Here is an [app](http://lemonjar.com/iosconsole/) that your user's can use to get the information from the console to then send to you.

Comment: I would also install to your device the same way they are to test. Xcode might be serving you a different build. Then you could use instruments to find the issue.